# Python regex to match multiple unique values

Tags: python, regex, unique

I need to match a string with specific letters but none of the letters should be duplicated. For example, [AEIOU] should not match 'AAEIOU' or 'AAEEIOU'. It should only match 'AEIOU' and the order of the letters should not matter. I tried using the exact quantifier with {} but did not work.

Comment: So you want to check if any string has duplicate letters ex ('aaxds' - true, 'hdks' - false, 'kshk' - true)? Or only if the duplicate it right next to the same character? Or is it only the one string 'AEIOU'

Comment: You might not need regex for this.... You could filter on something like `all(s.count(char) == 1 for char in 'AEIOU')` probably a simpler solution than that. Can you provide some expected inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

[`^(?!.*(.).*\1)[AEIOU]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/nrTTZz/1)

Whatever you put in the brackets will be the subset of characters you select from.

```
>>> import re
>>> tests = ['AAEIOU', 'AAEEIOU', 'AEIOU']
>>> for test in tests:
..    print(re.match(r'^(?!.*(.).*\1)[AEIOU]+$', test))
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='AEIOU'>
```

Comment: Good reference link with test cases. Excellent.

Comment: I have this regex saved for reference, pretty sure this is almost a duplicate.  Just can't find the original.

Comment: really good regex, can you explain it a little bit, I know what is lookaround but I didn't understand this one

Answer (score 0):

This maybe inefficient, but maybe use counters? Construct a counter for each, then check if they are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Not using regex, but you can use python string methods to count characters in a string. This can be used to develop a filter function that, effectively, can get you the results you want.

```
def has_all_unique(s):
    """Returns True of the string has exactly 1 of each vowel"""
    return all(s.count(char) == 1 for char in 'AEIOU')

tests = ['AAEIOU', 'AAEEIOU', 'AEIOU']

for match in filter(has_all_unique, tests):
    print(match)
```

Result would be just the one match meeting the condition,

```
AEIOU
```

This isn't the most performant option, but is simple and readable.

Comment: @MauricioCortazar appreciate your opinion, but I must disagree in this case. I love regex, it can be very expressive and take down deadly problems with a few characters... but put `^(?!.*(.).*\1)[AEIOU]+$` and `all(s.count(char) == 1 for char in 'AEIOU')` in front of 10 junior engineers and I think the results would speak to which one is easier to understand and describe without a reference or regex parser.

Comment: you're right, but i assume that everyone know regex